# Does Catholicism teach that there is a cyclic creation of the world?

Tags: catholicism, creation

Many religions, like Hinduism teach that the world is in a [cycle of creation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_model): creation then preservation then destruction (fading, annihilation) of the world then creation of a new world, in a repeated cycles, and so on.

The mysticism of many religions adopt this view, i.e: creation of the world is eternal process, coming from no beginning and going to no end, in repeated cycles.

What is the opinion of Catholic Church regarding this matter?

Comment: As @DJClayworth pointed out, all mainstream Christian traditions teach **one time** creation "ex nihilo" and **one time** either re-creation / transformation of this universe into an eternal version (after purging it from evil).  This is one quite central teaching, so if you're trying to "make Christianity fit" with a universal religion / mysticism, you will end up distorting Christianity.  (BTW, I did not downvote your question).

Comment: Up-votes are earned by questions which _show research effort and that are useful and clear_. Throwing out a blanket criticism of 'dogmatic stance' is not going to endear you to the community.

Comment: An `eschatological` world view of history and destiny, beginning with the creation of the world and the concept that God works through history, and ending with a resurrection of the dead and final judgment and world to come.

Answer (score 4):

None of the main parts of Christianity adhere to a cyclic view of creation. The Christian scriptures speak of the creation of the world (meaning the universe) by God "in the beginning" (meaning that nothing happened before that). Christians consider the creation was "Ex Nihilo" meaning that it was from nothing - there was no material from which the universe was made.

Likewise the scriptures speak of an end times of being with God which will last for ever. The "new world" will not be destroyed, not even for another creation.

Answer (score 3):

It's [*de fide*](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=32992), a truth of the Catholic faith, that God created the universe a finite time in the past and that the universe will end a finite time into the future. Thinking the universe is eternal is a [heresy](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33902).

The Fourth Lateran Council pronounced ([Denzinger 4](http://patristica.net/denzinger/#n400)28-9):

> Firmly we believe and we confess simply that the true God […] by His own omnipotent power at once from **the beginning of time** created each creature from nothing

and that He will

> come at **the end of time**, to judge the living and the dead

Scriptural proofs ([*Fundamentals of Catholic Dogma*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7262) bk. 2, ch. 1, §6, 1.):

> [John 17:5](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=50&ch=17&l=5-#x): “And now glorify thou me, O Father, with thyself, with the glory which I had before the world was with thee.” [Eph. 1:4](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=56&ch=1&l=4-#x): “He chose us in Him (Christ) even before the foundation of the world.” [Ps. 101:26](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=21&ch=101&l=26-#x): “In the beginning, O Lord, thou foundest the earth.” Cf. [Gn. 1:1](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=1&ch=1&l=1-#x); [Pro. 8:22](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=22&ch=8&l=22-#x) et seq.; [Ps. 89:2](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=21&ch=89&l=2-#x); [John 17:24](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=50&ch=17&l=5-#x).

St. Thomas Aquinas defended this Catholic truth, against those (e.g., the Greeks, Aristotle) who believed the universe to be eternal, in his short work [*De aeternitate mundi* (*On the Eternity of the World*)](https://isidore.co/aquinas/DeEternitateMundi.htm). He argues this truth can only be known by divine revelation.

Comment: off course the universe has beginning and end, but I am talking about cyclic annihilation and recreation of the universe. For me, the creation is ex-materia not ex-nihilo.

Comment: "_For me, the creation is ex-materia not ex-nihilo._" Then it seems you'd consider this _materia_ (a creature) eternal. No creature is eternal according to Catholic teaching.